# using ftp4j to connect using FTPES to IBM MVS OS/390 server

Tags: java, python, m2crypto, ftps, ftp4j

I am trying to connect FTPES server (IBM MVS OS/390), when trying with ftp4j I am getting PASS failed exception when using their example code

```
it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=530, message= PASS command failed]
```

I tried using python as well using ftplib as well as M2Crypto ftpslib, all these returning the same error "530 PASS command failed"

any clue?

```
def connect(self):
    try:
        ctx = SSL.Context('sslv23')
        self.ftps = ftpslib.FTP_TLS(ssl_ctx=ctx)
        self.ftps.connect(self.host,self.port)
        self.ftps.auth_tls()
        self.ftps.set_pasv(1)
        self.ftps.sendcmd('USER %s' % self.username) # '331 Please specify the password.'
        self.ftps.sendcmd('PASS %s' % self.password)

        #self.ftps.login(self.username, self.password)
        self.ftps.prot_p()
        print('logged in sucessfuly')
        self.ftps.cwd('XXXX')
    except Exception,e:
        self.ftps = None
        self.logger.warning("Exception raised while connecting FTPS server, %s" % ("*** Caught exception: %s: %s" % (e.__class__, e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

All the ports FTPES in java, python as well as working charmingly except that, I missed the wrong username while copy and pasting from source to properties file. This was found when I tried with filezilla to connect to the host with authentication details caught me with failure, during that period, I verified my credentials and caught me with wrong information put earlier in the properties file.